# Parse a txt file or an input using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Have the following code:

```
$input = @'
Country: USA, CHINA, 
City : NY, BEIJING
Ranking : 1, 2

Country: BRAZIL, ARGENTINA
City: RIO, BUENOS AIRES
Ranking : 10,11
'@

$array = @()
$input | ForEach-Object {
    $writeobj = $false
    $obj = New-Object System.Object
    if ($_ -match 'Country*') {
        $Country = ($_ -split ':')[1]
    }
    if ($_ -match 'City*') {
        $City = ($_ -split ':')[2]
        $writeobj = $true
    }
    if ($_ -match 'Ranking*') {
        $Ranking = ($_ -split ':')[3]
        $writeobj = $true
    }
    if ($writeobj) {
        $obj | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name Country -Value $Country
        $obj | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name City -Value $City
        $obj | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name Ranking -Value $Ranking
        $array += $obj
    }
}
$file =  "path"
$array | Export-Csv -Path $file\test1.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

The code is working but its only grabbing the first text below:

```
Country: USA, CHINA, 
City : NY, BEIJING
Ranking : 1, 2

Country: BRAZIL, ARGENTINA
City: RIO, BUENOS AIRES
Ranking : 10,11
```

It is only exporting the first one: Countries  USA and China, but the text below does not get exported  such as Brazil and Argentina. Any reason why?

Comment: It's is because your index is wrong on your `split` . They should all be: `($_ -split ':')[1]`

Comment: @jrider  its not , because if i add [1] to all of them - i get the following in 3 columns

Comment: USA, CHINA   USA,CHINA  USA,CHINA

Comment: I see. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Do not use `$input` as a variable name. It is an automatic variable and you will experience breaks in unexpected ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because the `Foreach` is not going by each line.

This is a quick and easy way to fix that by adding:

```
$blob = $stuff -split '\r?\n'
```

Update: mklement0 TheIncorrigible1 both bring up good point. You should not use `$input` as a variable. And there is a better expression for new lines.

Example:

```
$stuff=@'
Country: USA, CHINA, 
City : NY, BEIJING
Ranking : 1, 2

Country: BRAZIL, ARGENTINA
City: RIO, BUENOS AIRES
Ranking : 10,11
'@
$blob = $stuff -split '\r?\n'
$array = @()
$blob | foreach-object {
$writeobj = $false
$obj = New-Object System.Object
If ($_ -match 'Country*') {
    $Country = ($_ -split ':')[1]
    Write-Host "County: " $Country -ForegroundColor Yellow
}
If ($_ -match 'City*') {
    $City = ($_ -split ':')[1]
    Write-Host "City: " $City -ForegroundColor Yellow
    $writeobj = $true
}
If ($_ -match 'Ranking*') {
    $Ranking = ($_ -split ':')[1]
    Write-Host "Ranking: " $Ranking -ForegroundColor Yellow
    $writeobj = $true
}
If ($writeobj){
    $obj | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Country -value $Country
    $obj | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name City -value $City
     $obj | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Ranking-value $Ranking
    $array += $obj
}
}

$array.Country -join ""
$array.City -join ""
$array.'Ranking-Value' -join ""
$array
```

Comment: Its not picking up the 2 set of data

Comment: How do I combine all Countries into one line, all cities into another line and the same for Rankings.

Comment: You could call the property names. Example: `$array.City` That would list the City members

Comment: Output :  Countries: USA, CHINA, BRAZIL, ARGENTINA     CITIES(2nd line)  - all cities , "", """ ,""   and same for ranking.

Comment: Where would you add in the code - next to wrrite host ?

Comment: If you wanted to display each member of `$array` per line, you would want to do something like this: `$array.Country -join ""` . You don't need a `write-host` as long it is after your `foreach`. Updated answer to include

Comment: Still not working, its not showing the output  as mentioned by Theo - answer below

Comment: @user9191 if you wanted that output all you would do is call `$array` you can put it at the bottom. I will update the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197940/discussion-between-user-9191-and-jrider).

Comment: The code is working at the moment. Just wondering if theres a way to make sure all the input are being displayed in the ouput ?Sometimes the output is missing 1 or 2 content from the input

Answer (score 2):

`$input` is an [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-3.0). Avoid re-defining those and use a different variable name instead.

With that said, you cannot process the input the way you do (line-by-line) when the data you want to collect into one object is spread across multiple consecutive lines. What you want to do here is split your data at 2 consecutive line breaks and then parse the fragments into custom objects.

```
$data = Get-Content 'input.txt' | Out-String

$data -split '\r?\n\r?\n' | ForEach-Object {
    $prop = $_.Trim() -replace '\s*:\s*', '=' |
            ConvertFrom-StringData

    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property $prop
} | Export-Csv 'output.csv' -NoType
```

If you have PowerShell v3 or newer you can further simplify that code to something like this:

```
$data = Get-Content 'input.txt' -Raw

$data -split '\r?\n\r?\n' | ForEach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject]($_.Trim() -replace '\s*:\s*', '=' | ConvertFrom-StringData)
} | Export-Csv 'output.csv' -NoType
```

Note that this does not work for here-strings, though, because for reasons unknown to me Microsoft decided that it was a good idea to collapse consecutive line breaks in those.

Comment: The code is working at the moment. Just wondering if theres a way to make sure all the input are being displayed in the ouput ?Sometimes the output is missing 1 or 2 content from the input

Comment: @user9191 Please be more specific about what is missing.

Comment: For example , the input is a list of countries right ? that comes from $data = Get-Content 'input.txt' | Out-String. Inside of this input text there's a list of 100 countries, but only 50 are showing on the ouput. A check or something that will let the user if all 100 countries are being displayed for example

Comment: Please post a followup question with the code you're using and a sample input file that would allow us to reproduce/debug the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this using Regex

Note: Do not use `$input` as variable name, because it is an [Automatic Variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-6#input) in PowerShell.

```
$txt = @'
Country: USA, CHINA, 
City : NY, BEIJING
Ranking : 1, 2

Country: BRAZIL, ARGENTINA
City: RIO, BUENOS AIRES
Ranking : 10,11
'@

# Create a regex (for your convenience using named groups)
$re     = [regex] 'Country *: *(?<country>.+)\r?\nCity *: *(?<city>.+)\r?\nRanking *: *(?<ranking>.+)'
$match  = $re.Match($txt)
$result = while ($match.Success) {
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        'Country' = ($match.Groups['country'].Value).Trim() -replace ',$'
        'City'    = ($match.Groups['city'].Value).Trim()
        'Ranking' = ($match.Groups['ranking'].Value).Trim()
    }
    $match = $match.NextMatch()
} 

# output on screen:
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# export to CSV:
$file = 'D:\test1.csv'
$result | Export-Csv -Path $file -NoTypeInformation
```

Output on screen looks like this:

> ```
> Country           City              Ranking
> -------           ----              -------
> USA, CHINA        NY, BEIJING       1, 2   
> BRAZIL, ARGENTINA RIO, BUENOS AIRES 10,11
> ```

Regex details:

```
Country          Match the characters “Country” literally
\                Match the character “ ” literally
   *             Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
:                Match the character “:” literally
\                Match the character “ ” literally
   *             Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
(?<country>      Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference with name “country”
   .             Match any single character that is not a line break character
      +          Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)
\r               Match a carriage return character
   ?             Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\n               Match a line feed character
City             Match the characters “City” literally
\                Match the character “ ” literally
   *             Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
:                Match the character “:” literally
\                Match the character “ ” literally
   *             Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
(?<city>         Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference with name “city”
   .             Match any single character that is not a line break character
      +          Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)
\r               Match a carriage return character
   ?             Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\n               Match a line feed character
Ranking          Match the characters “Ranking” literally
\                Match the character “ ” literally
   *             Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
:                Match the character “:” literally
\                Match the character “ ” literally
   *             Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
(?<ranking>      Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference with name “ranking”
   .             Match any single character that is not a line break character
      +          Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)
```

Comment: Check out `ConvertFrom-StringData`. No need for regex in `K=V` text patterns.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I know. Ansgar already used that in his answer. This is simply a different approach.

Comment: Sometimes i get an empty spreadsheet. Not really sure why . Also how could i adjsut the code that returns all the Countries, Cities and Ranking in one line separated by commas as the ouput. On the spreadsheet it returns separated

Comment: @user9191 Can you elaborate on that? I don't see the (spreadsheet) point of slamming everything in one comma separated line.. Please give an example of this desired output.

Comment: Theo I received an empty spreadsheet as an output.  Not sure why to be honest.  List all countries in one cell, instead of different rows, list all cities in another cell , rankings etc.. Desired output the same one you posted . Thanks

Comment: @user9191 Are you sure your input text is like you posted? If you're reading from a textfile, make sure you do `$txt = Get-Content -Path 'THE INPUT FILE' -Raw`. Without the Raw switch you'll get an array of strings instead on one single string.

Comment: @user9191 P.S. The output is a csv file which you can open in a spreadsheet application like Excel. It is not an Exlel .xlsx file.

Comment: The code is working at the moment. Just wondering if theres a way to make sure all the input are being displayed in the ouput ?Sometimes the output is missing 1 or 2 content from the input

Comment: @user9191 That will depend on the input file. Without examples I cannot say why some input could get missing. All we have to work with is what you have posted.

Comment: I see, but it will be hard to have a check based on my input that i have on my code above -